# What does the symbol $\omega$ stand for in statistics?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, random-variables, expected-value

I was reading an answer here in math stackexchange and it mentioned this:

> Linearity of Expectation then follows from *its* definition.
>
> $\begin{align} \mathsf E(X+Y) =&~ \sum_{\omega\in\Omega}
> (X+Y)(\omega)~\mathsf P(\omega) \\[1ex] =&~ \sum_{\omega\in \Omega}
> X(\omega)~\mathsf P(\omega)+\sum_{\omega\in \Omega} Y(\omega)~\mathsf
> P(\omega) \\[1ex] =&~ \mathsf E(X)+\mathsf E(Y) \end{align}$

What does the symbol $\omega$ stand for?

Comment: Note that $\omega$ is just the dummy variable of the summations, so it doesn't really have a meaning here (the equation would have exactly the same meaning if you replaced all the $\omega$'s with some other variable).  Maybe your question is really what $\Omega$ means?

Comment: Less to do with statistics and more to do with random variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are dealing with a [probability space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_space) $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$; and your [random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_space#Random_variables) $X$ is a measurable function $X\colon \Omega\to S$, from the *sample space* to the *state space*.

Then, $\omega$ is just an element of $\Omega$. $X(\omega)$ is the realization of the random variable, $\mathbb{P}(\omega)$ is the probability of $\omega$.

Answer (score 2):

$\omega\ $ stands for an *outcome*, i. e. for an element from the sample space $\Omega$.